# How can you put a default image in multer if no image is uploaded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, multer

I'm trying to set up multer but I'm having some issues with the image, as for now, when I don't upload any image, the server gives me an error which doesn't allow me to continue. I want that even if the image is not uploaded, to still store the values in the database.

This is where I have my multer configured:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const multer  = require('multer');
    
    const Clients = require('../models/clients.js')
    
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, "../emaildragger/public/uploads")
      },
      filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, file.originalname)
      }
    })
    
    const upload = multer({storage: storage})
    
    router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
        Clients.find()
        .then(client => res.json(client))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error:' + err))
    })
    
    router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
      Clients.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(client => res.json(client))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error" + err))
    })
    
    router.route('/add').post(upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
      
        const newClient = new Clients({
          image: req.file.originalname,
          firstName: req.body.firstName,
          lastName: req.body.lastName,
          weight: req.body.weight,
          BMI: req.body.BMI
        })
    
        newClient.save()
        .then (() => res.json(newClient))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('error' + err))
    })
    
    module.exports = router
```

Here is my models:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    var clientsSchema = new Schema(
      {
        image: 
          { type: String, required: false, default: 'Screenshot_293.png'},
        firstName: { type: String, required: true },
        lastName: { type: String, required: true },
        weight: { type: String, required: false },
        BMI: { type: String, required: false }
      }
    );
    
    
    const Clients = mongoose.model("clients", clientsSchema)
    
    
    module.exports = Clients
```

Comment: Can you add the error to the question?

Comment: no error, just that nothing happens

Comment: But you said in question that server gives you an error which doesn't allow you to continue.

Comment: ```POST http://localhost:4000/clients/add 500 (Internal Server Error)``` this is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your server because you added `Multer` as an middleware, and later in your controller you are trying to access the `originalname` of the uploaded file. If you didn't send the image, then `Multer` will not parse and upload it, and the file will not exist. In that case you will try to access to the `originalname` property of something that does not exist, so your server will throw an error.

Try to change you code like this:

```js
router.route('/add').post(upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {

   let client = {
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      weight: req.body.weight,
      BMI: req.body.BMI
   }  
   if(req.file && req.file.originalname) client.image = req.file.originalname;
   
   const newClient = new Clients(client)

   newClient.save()
   .then (() => res.json(newClient))
   .catch(err => res.status(400).json('error' + err))
})
```